flutter talks to node js api locally however when I run it on off the server I get a error
I have a flutter app that talks to a nodejs api called surplusItems
when I enter a cpsnumber and hit enter key it talks to the api and displays the item description that matches that entered cps number. this all works locally but when i build the app and run it off my web server I get the following error:
main.dart.js:41502 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/surplusItems?CPSNumber=no%20 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

and when I run it with the servers it with my url like this
  final url = Uri.parse('http://server IP address:3000/surplusItems?CPSNumber=$cpsNumber');

I get a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
here is my flutter code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:surplus/form_data.dart';
import 'package:surplus/summary.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormPageState createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  List<FormData> forms = [];
  String? _selectedSchool;
final List<String> _schools = [
  'Alpha Hart Lewis Elementary',
  'Battle High School',
  'Benton Elementary',
  'Beulah Ralph Elementary',
  'Blue Ridge Elementary',
  'Business Office',
  'CORE-Boys and Girls Town',
  'CORE-Quest',
  'Cedar Ridge Elementary',
  'Center for Early Learning North',
  'Columbia Area Career Center',
  'Derby Ridge Elementary',
  'Douglass High Adult Basic Ed',
  'Douglass High School',
  'Early Childhood Discovery Cntr',
  'Early Childhood Special Ed',
  'Eliot Battle Elementary',
  'Facilities & Construction Srv',
  'Fairview Elementary',
  'Field Building',
  'Gentry Middle School',
  'Gifted Center',
  'Grant Elementary',
  'Hickman High School',
  'Jefferson Middle School',
  'John Warner Middle School',
  'Juvenile Justice Center',
  'Lange Middle School',
  'Locust Street Expressive Arts Elementary',
  'Mail Check',
  'Midway Heights Elementary',
  'Mill Creek Elementary',
  'Moving On Together',
  'New Haven Elementary',
  'Nutrition Services',
  'Oakland Middle School',
  'Park Avenue Head Start',
  'Parkade Elementary',
  'Paxton-Keeley Elementary',
  'Rainforest School',
  'Ridgeway Elementary',
  'Rock Bridge Elementary',
  'Rock Bridge High School',
  'Rosetta Avenue Learning Center',
  'Russell Blvd Elementary',
  'Shepard Blvd Elementary',
  'Smithton Middle School',
  'Two Mile Prairie Elementary',
  'West Blvd Elementary',
  'West Middle School',
];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    forms.add(FormData());
  }

  void addNewForm() {
    setState(() {
      forms.add(FormData());
    });
  }

void reviewData(BuildContext context) async {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => SummaryPage(
        formData: forms.where((element) => element.cpsNumber.isNotEmpty).toList(),
        school: _selectedSchool ?? "",
      ),
    ),
  );
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Surplus Asset Disposal Form'),
          centerTitle: true,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color(0xFF005570), // Set text color to white

        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: _selectedSchool,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Select School',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedSchool = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: _schools.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: forms.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyCustomForm(
                  formData: forms[index],
                  onCpsNumberTyped: addNewForm,
                  onDataUpdated: (data) {
                    setState(() => forms[index] = data);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => reviewData(context),
                child: Text('REVIEW'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color(0xFF005570), // Set text color to white

            ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final FormData formData;
  final VoidCallback onCpsNumberTyped;
  final Function(FormData) onDataUpdated;

  MyCustomForm({required this.formData, required this.onCpsNumberTyped, required this.onDataUpdated});

  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final TextEditingController _cpsNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemDescriptionController = TextEditingController();
  String? selectedReason;
  bool _isFirstInput = true;

final List<String> _reasonsForSurplus = [
  'No Longer Used',
  'Burned Out',
  'Broken',
  'Extinction',
  'Obsolete',
];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cpsNumberController.text = widget.formData.cpsNumber;
    _itemDescriptionController.text = widget.formData.itemDescription;
    selectedReason = widget.formData.selectedReason;
    _cpsNumberController.addListener(() {
      final cpsNumber = _cpsNumberController.text;
      if (cpsNumber.isNotEmpty && _isFirstInput) {
        _fetchItemDescription(cpsNumber);
        widget.onCpsNumberTyped();
        _isFirstInput = false; // Prevents continuous addition of forms
      }
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(cpsNumber: cpsNumber));
    });
    _itemDescriptionController.addListener(() {
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: _itemDescriptionController.text));
    });
  }

void _fetchItemDescription(String cpsNumber) async {
  // Update the URL to match the new API endpoint.
  // Assuming your server is running locally and accessible from your Flutter app,
  // you might need to replace 'localhost' with your local IP address when running on a real device.
  final url = Uri.parse('http://server IP address:3000/surplusItems?CPSNumber=$cpsNumber');
  //final url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/surplusItems?CPSNumber=$cpsNumber');

  try {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      if (data != null && data['Description'] != null) {
        setState(() {
          _itemDescriptionController.text = data['Description'];
          widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: data['Description']));
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _itemDescriptionController.text = 'Description not found';
          widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: 'Description not found'));
        });
      }
    } else {
      print('Server error: ${response.statusCode}');
      // It's a good practice to handle HTTP errors gracefully.
      setState(() {
        _itemDescriptionController.text = 'Error fetching description';
        widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: 'Error fetching description'));
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to fetch item description: $e');
    setState(() {
      _itemDescriptionController.text = 'Failed to connect';
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: 'Failed to connect'));
    });
  }
}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: _cpsNumberController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'CPS Number',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  // Trigger fetchItemDescription when Enter key is pressed
                  _fetchItemDescription(value);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _itemDescriptionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Item Description',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                maxLines: null,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: selectedReason,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Reason for Surplus',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedReason = newValue;
                    widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(selectedReason: newValue));
                  });
                },
                items: _reasonsForSurplus.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cpsNumberController.dispose();
    _itemDescriptionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

here is my api code
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Database configuration
const config = {
    user: 'db username',
    password: 'db password',
    server: 'db server name ', // Your database server
    database: 'database name ',
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true,
        encrypt: true, // For Azure SQL
        trustServerCertificate: true, // Only for development!
    },
};

// Middleware
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' })); // Setup CORS
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Parse JSON bodies

// Endpoint to get an item description by CPSNumber
app.get('/surplusItems', async (req, res) => {
    const { CPSNumber } = req.query;
    if (!CPSNumber) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "CPSNumber parameter is missing" });
    }

    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        const result = await sql.query`SELECT Description FROM SurplusItemsNew WHERE CPSNumber = ${CPSNumber}`;
        sql.close();

        if (result.recordset.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "No item found with the given CPSNumber" });
        }

        res.json(result.recordset[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
        sql.close();
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
});

// Endpoint to submit multiple surplus items
app.post('/submitSurplusItems', async (req, res) => {
    const items = req.body.items;
    if (!items) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No items provided" });
    }

    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        const transaction = new sql.Transaction();
        await transaction.begin();
        const request = new sql.Request(transaction);

        for (const item of items) {
            await request.query`INSERT INTO SurplusItemsNew (BuildingName, CPSNumber, Description, ReasonDescription, SurplusStatus) VALUES (${item.school}, ${item.cpsNumber}, ${item.itemDescription}, ${item.selectedReason}, 1)`;
        }

        await transaction.commit();
        res.json({ success: true, message: "Items successfully inserted." });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Internal server error" });
    }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

It runs when I run it locally but not when I load the app on my web server
what am I doing wrong?
any help would be amazing!!!!!


if your issue is - running api in local as localhost and mobile app as
Emulator or Physical Device

you can't directly send request from mobile to local api with localhost:port ,
Because you emulator consider itself as localhost not your development machine.
In order to achieve this without deploying api to cloud you have to use something

ngrok : it will run api as SSL so you don't have to deal with SSL problems
Development Machine IP : in this case you have to disable SSL verification in Flutter

here is an example Dart code:
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  http.Client client = http.Client();
  client.badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
}

I've used http/http.dart package you can read the document of the package that you are using.

thank you so much for the reply if I use the Development Machine IP's do I need ngrok  installed to that machine? also the code snippet you shared do I use that in my form.dart code or in the main.dart code? also this is a flutter web app not a mobile app so will your answer work with flutter web apps? thanks again for all the help
